# Making new expressions within a function using existing quosures (dplyr programming)

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, quosure

I am trying to make "new expressions" based off quosures within a function from its arguments, but am unsure of how exactly to make this new expression.

Here is an example where I pass a numerator and denominator and would ideally do mutations on both but also would like to do a mutation where I divide them:

```
df <- tibble(
  g1 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  g2 = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1),
  a = sample(5), 
  b = sample(5)
)

my_divide <- function(df, numerator, denominator) {
  numerator <- enquo(numerator)
  denominator <- enquo(denominator)

  df %>%
    mutate(p = !!numerator / !!denominator)
}

my_divide(df, g1 , g2)
```

This fails with the following error:

```
Error in !denominator : invalid argument type
```

I could easily pass the expression as its own argument and enquo() it, but this doesn't scale for more expressions. I could also create temporary columns in the dataframe from the base quosures and then calculate the expression directly, but this seems too verbose. I imagine there's a simpler way to do this

Answer (score 2):

**1)** `/` has higher precedence than `!` but we want `!` to bind more tightly since we want !! to be applied prior to the division, not afterwards.  Put parentheses around `!!numerator` and then it will work.   See `?Syntax` for documentation of the precedence rules used by the R language.

**2)** Another possibility but without rlang/tidyeval is:

```
my_divide <- function(df, numerator, denominator = 1) {
  eval.parent(substitute(
   df %>% mutate(p = numerator / denominator)
  ))
}

my_divide(df, g1 / g2)
my_divide(df, g1, g2)
```

Comment: Close, but I would like to be able to do arbitrary expressions given numerator/denominator as opposed to having to specify the division expression in the function call

Comment: Please clarify.  This already allows numerator to be passed as an arbitrary expression and lets the sample call in the question work without error.

Comment: Ah I see, I had a typo in the question that replicated through - I thought your example passed g1 / g2 as the expression in my_divide

Comment: Yes, I used the same code shown in the question and it works.  `my_divide(df, g1, g2)` would also work.  Also, the arguments can be arbitrary expressions

Comment: Thanks - would still hope to see it using tidy/dplyr syntax, but good to know this works

Comment: Your code will work if you put parentheses around `!!numerator` .

Answer (score 1):

Use backticks to call the divide function.

```
my_divide <- function(df, numerator, denominator) {
  n <- enquo(numerator)
  d <- enquo(denominator)

  df %>%
    mutate(p = `/`(!!n, !!d))
}

my_divide(df, g1 , g2)
```

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to pass it as an quoted expression for later evaluation

```
my_divide <- function(df, exprs) {  

 df %>%
    mutate(p = !! exprs) 
 }

my_divide(df, quote(g1/ g2))
# A tibble: 5 x 5
#    g1    g2     a     b     p
#  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <dbl>
#1  1.00  1.00     5     2 1.00 
#2  1.00  2.00     2     4 0.500
#3  2.00  1.00     3     1 2.00 
#4  2.00  2.00     4     5 1.00 
#5  2.00  1.00     1     3 2.00
```